# Check what Object represents

Tags: vb.net

I have defined a variable like this:

```
Dim nObj As Object
```

Then I would like to either say...

```
nObj = Me.RichTextBox1
```

... or ...

```
nObj = Me.ListView1
```

... or ....

```
nObj = "Just a test"
```

How could I now check what "nObj" actually is?

I have tried

```
    If nObj Is RichTextBox Then
        'do something
    End I
```

But that gave the error "RichTextBox is a class type and can not be used an expression".

Thank you!

Comment: Try TypeOf https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/typeof-operator

Comment: @jwatts1980 Thank you very much, it works!

Comment: No problem. I went ahead and posted this as an answer to round out the thread.

Answer (score 0):

[Try using `TypeOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/typeof-operator)

```
Dim nObj As Object

'some condition
nObj = Me.RichTextBox1
'some condition
nObj = Me.ListView1
'some condition
nObj = "Just a test"

If TypeOf nObj Is RichTextBox Then
    'do something
ElseIf TypeOf nObj Is ListView Then
    'do something
ElseIf TypeOf nObj Is String Then
    'do something
Else
    'do default something
End If
```